# Why should Vbb not exceed the barrier potential values?

Tags: transistors

This has been mentioned in the book

***The voltage VBE across the forward-biased junction is very low (for a germanium transistor, VBE = 0.3 V; and for silicon transistor, 
VBE = 0.7 V). This requires that the battery voltage Vbb must also be of the same order***

[image]

Comment: Think what would happen **if** we didn't follow the advice and applied 1 V across base and emitter. Realize that the Base-Emitter junction behaves very similar to a **diode**. What does the Voltage-current relation of a diode look like? In the real world, a transistor is never used like this because if we get Vbb wrong (and the optimal Vbb changes over temperature as well), the transistor can be destroyed.

Comment: Note that you don't ever design a real bias network that way -- if the author is any good, you'll soon read an explanation of why, and how to design a *proper* bias network.

Comment: @TimWescott yes it is mentioned in the next para itself

Answer (score 1):

To my opinion, the quoted wording is rather confusing: "*The voltage VBE across the forward-biased junction is very low*".

In fact, the user is biasing the B-E path with an **externally applied** voltage. Hence, it is not "*very low*" but it depends on the selected biasing network. And this voltage must not be much larger than the mentioned 0.7 volts - unless you are designing a transistor stage with a very large collector current Ic=f(VBE).

Perhaps the author was referring to the internally developped diffusion voltage across the B-E junction. However, in this case, he must not speak about a "forward-biased junction" and he should use the term "diffusion voltage". This voltage acts as a kind of internal "barriere" that must be neutralized (compensated) by the external applied voltage.

Of course, the applied (or generated) voltage VBE is allowed to be somewhat larger than the diffusion voltage. In this case, it is best to remember the well-known Shockley equation: **Ic=Is[exp(VBE/Vt) - 1]**.

(Is: saturation current, Vt: temperature voltage). From this equation it is clear that we have a (small) collector current also for VBE=0.5 volts and a larger one for 0.75...0.8 volts.

**Comment**: Because of heating effects and other undesired influences it is dangerous - as mentioned by Bimpelrekki in his comment - to use the transistor stage in the shown simple ciruit. Instead, it is necessary to stablize the desired collctor current using negative feedback (emitter resistor).